# Can I expand the haptic feedback capabilities of the Surface Pro?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-surface

I notice that, when I touch the Windows logo area on the Surface Pro, it vibrates some. However, this vibration is *never* utilized elsewhere in the experience. **Is there any way I can expand this haptic feedback capability for more general use?** For instance, when I touch a button, type a virtual key, or long-touch.

Comment: Surface Pro is only available in the US and Canada. SO you don't get help at this point from many user. Ask it in the official MS forums: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/surfpro

Comment: Thanks, but I'll also hold out hope that the users here are able to give me an answer :3

Comment: If that single button is hardwired to vibrate then obviously nothing can be done, but if there's a software interface provided then I'm sure third party developers will start using it soon.